# Code Coverage for COBOL code in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, code-coverage, cobol

I want to include code coverage in my Jenkins pipeline. I am building a COBOL code and want to know if there are any plugins which support code coverage for COBOL on Jenkins.

I don't use Compuware Tool set so I cannot use Compuware Xpeditor Code coverage plugin.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Many big financial companies relies on [SONAR](https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonarcobol.html) to evaluate their COBOL source code

A pluggin exists for Jenkins. See [here](http://qualilogy.com/en/cobol-source-code-analysis-with-sonar-and-jenkins/) for the installation and setup

Answer (score 0):

Our [COBOL test coverage tool](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/COBOLTestCoverage.html?site=StackOverflow) handles (IBM Enterprise, implied by your Xpeditor note) COBOL and produces test coverage results. You'd probabaly have to reformat those results to plug into Jenkins but that's probably pretty minor string hacking.

Comment: Ira, I was crawling through the golden `parsing` badge holders - could you have a look [at my question with an open bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405055/nodevisitor-class-for-peg-parser-in-python/55445187#55445187) ?