# Representing an AST in C with different structs for types of nodes

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I have many structs which look something like:

```
typedef struct ast_function_node
{        
    int node_type;
    ast_node* arguments;
    symbol* sym;
} ast_function_node;

typedef struct ast_while_node
{
    int node_type;
    ast_node* condition;
    ast_node* while_branch;
} ast_while_node;

typedef struct ast_assignment_node
{
    int node_type;
    symbol* sym;
    ast_node* value;
} ast_assignment_node;

typedef struct ast_number_node
{
    int node_type;
    double value;
} ast_number_node;

typedef struct ast_string_node 
{
    int node_type;
    char* value;
} ast_string_node;

etc...
```

And a base struct:

```
typedef struct // Basic AST node
{
  int node_type;
  struct ast_node* left;
  struct ast_node* right;
} ast_node;
```

I can populate this AST pretty easily, but when it comes to traversing it I get stuck in a hell of typecasting. If I wanted to visit each node, look at its type and then do something accordingly, what is the best way of doing this? Just casting it to the base node of `ast_node` won't do it of course.

Comment: If you extend each struct with the elements of `ast_node` you would be able to simplify the traversal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I'd do this in C is to use a `struct` with a `union` member:

```
typedef struct ast_function
{        
    ast_node* arguments;
    symbol* sym;
} ast_function;

typedef struct ast_while
{
    ast_node* condition;
    ast_node* while_branch;
} ast_while;

typedef struct ast_assignment
{
    symbol* sym;
    ast_node* value;
} ast_assignment;

/* Etc. */

typedef struct ast_node {
  int node_type;
  /* See anonymous unions in any C reference */
  union {
    ast_function   function_data;
    ast_while      while_data;
    ast_assignment assignment_data;
    /* Etc. */
  };
}
```

Then you don't need casts at all:

```
switch (node->node_type) {
  case AST_FUNCTION:
    handle_function(&node->function_data); 
    break;
  /* Etc. */
}
```

If you make `node_type` an `enum` instead of an `int`, the compiler will be able to warn you if you miss a possibility in your `switch` statement.

Comment: rici, I was crawling through the golden `parsing` badge holders - could you have a look [at my question with an open bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55405055/nodevisitor-class-for-peg-parser-in-python/55445187#55445187) ?